# PHP mysql query for fetching datas from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have two tables

**users**

[image]

**games**

[image]

**My requirement**

```
[
 {
   users:{
     id: "1",
     user: "user1",
     games:[
       {
         id : "1",
         game_names : "football"
       }
       {
         id : "2",
         game_names : "cricket"
       }
       {
         id : "3",
         game_names : "athletics"
       }
       {
         id : "4",
         game_names : "badminton"
       }
     ]
   }
   users: {
     id : "2",
     user : "user2",
     games :[
       {
         id : "3",
         game_names : "athletics"
       }
       {
         id : "4",
         game_names : "badminton"
       }
       {
         id: "5",
         game_names : "basketball"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

**What I am using Now**

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,games.game_names as games
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN games ON users.games=games.id 
GROUP BY users.id") or die(mysql_error());

while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {        
    $users[] = array(
                'user'=>array(
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'user' => $user['user'],                        
                    'games' =>  $user['games']          
                )
    );  
} 
$output = json_encode(array('statics' => $users));
echo $output;
    ?>
```

**But I am Getting**

```
{
 statics: [
   {
    users: {
       id: "1",
       user: "user1",
       games: "1,2,3,4"
    }
   },
   {
    users: {
     id: "2",
     user: "user2",
     games: "3,4,5"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But I can't get second array **games**

How should i need to change my code php code.

Comment: Please, please, please _stop using the deprecated `mysql_*`extension_. Read [the read box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect). Learn to use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*` (or both)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ok bro. First i have to learn basics. Then i will move to advanced PDO

Comment: Normalize that first table and no need to learn obsolete basics, learn the basics of mysqli if you want something similar to mysql

Comment: Please don't use any mysq_* functions as they are deprecated. Consider using [PDO](http://be1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: @PonrajPaul: Yes, first you have to learn the basics, but learn the basics with `mysqli_*` it has both an OO and a procedural API. Learning the basics using `mysql_*` is like learning Old English, only to then move on to modern Enlish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used this query working perfectly

```
SELECT users.*,games.game_names,games.id as games_id
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN games ON FIND_IN_SET(games.id,users.games)
```

[image]

now set php code according your requirment

Comment: I tried this...but it is coming like  {
statics: [
{
users: {
id: "1",
user: "user1",
games: "1,2,3,4"
}
},
{
users: {
id: "2",
user: "user2",
games: "3,4,5"
}
}
]
}

Comment: I need an array format inside games. And also need to get value instead of id

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do it directly in a query i guess. Instead of this you should normalize your model:

```
users
user_id
user_name

users_games
user_id
game_id

games
game_id
game_name
```

For your example the data will be:

```
users:
1,user1
2,user2

users_games:
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
2,5

games:
1,game1
2,game2
3,game3
4,game4
5,game5
```

After normalize you can execute this query witch gives you exactly what you want

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(games.game_names)
FROM users INNER JOIN users_games ON users.user_id=users_games.user_id
INNER JOIN games ON users_games.game_id = games.game_id GROUP BY users.user_id
```

I do not try the query, but it should work

**EDITED**:

Acording to @ShaktiPatel you can use find_in_set, (i do not know about the function `FIND_IN_SET`) with a group_concat:

```
SELECT users.*,GROUP_CONCAT(games.game_names)
FROM users 
INNER JOIN games ON FIND_IN_SET(games.id,users.games) GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Do i need to change my table structure

Comment: It's very recommended, if you cannot change it, then you should use the query given by Shakti Patel, i will edit my answer with a modification of his query

Comment: I tried with ur edited code..But no changes. Did u check my array in while loop.. do i need change anything in that area??

Comment: sorry i forgot to change the left join with `INNER JOIN` (or `JOIN`), obviously if you want an array for the field `game_names` then you should do an `explode`

Answer (score 0):

You Have To use Inner Join Instead Of left join

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM users 
INNER JOIN games ON users.games=games.id 
GROUP BY users.id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Wrong, look at the values of `users.games`

Comment: inner join also giving same output